# Location updates when app is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

Is there a way for an app to send a notification when the user approaches a certain predefined location (lat, long) while then app is fully closed? From what I have read, since iOS 7 there is no way to relaunch an app after it has been closed by the user. What I need is for the location of the user to be constantly monitored by the app whether or not it is running, in the background or closed, and when a certain location matches with another location set by the user, a notification should appear. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you look at the location programming guide?  It explains how you can use region monitoring and significant location change updates in the background. There was also a good session on location at WWDC this year - you can get the video in the Apple developer site

Comment: iOS 7 removed the functionality - But iOS 7.1 brought it back in - With Geofences / iBeacons apple with open you app for about 10 seconds or so - Enough time to show a notification :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using region monitoring. The way this works is you set up a coordinate with a defined radius (region) an register it as a region to be monitored  and the app will tell you when the user has enter or exited that region.

You can read all about it here: [Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)